# I want to create a view, named route that selects the road's name and length, which have a greater than or equal to average length. Here is my script

Tags: mysql, sql

CREATE VIEW routes AS
SELECT
name, length
FROM
roads
WHERE
length >= AVG(length)
GROUP BY name;

Comment: Okay, so what is your **question**? What happens when you try to use the code? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different? please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your question is about how to use average in this case. You could write as a subquery, but may depend on your version of MySql.

```
CREATE VIEW longroads AS
   SELECT 
     name, length
   FROM  
     roads
   WHERE 
     length >= (select avg(length) from roads);
```

Note: I'm not sure on your intention to have GROUP BY in your query, but I don't believe you want it. And I would consider changing the name of your "length" column.